# How to find complete installer location which is installed using small size initiator .exe on Windows 10

Tags: installation, files, windows-10, anti-virus, search

Some time companies give small setup.exe file, for example 2 MB .exe of Kaspersky which we run and that will connect to the company server, download complete installer/setup and install the software. So I want to know the location of downloaded full setup in this process so that later I can use it as offline installer.

while running 2 MB .exe I noticed the wizard was showing progress bar of "downloading in process" and then "installation in process" which mean it is 100% sure full set-up/installer is downloaded but where I couldn't able to locate it.

I already tried to find at Run --> temp, %temp%, %appdata%, and C drive but not able to locate it. Also tried FORFILE command on cmd but says access denied even through admin.

Can anybody please give any suggestion to locate this Kaspersky full installer location on my Windows 10 machine

Comment: The web installer always deletes temporary full installer after installation. Try to find a needed version of Kaspersky on the website or ask Kaspersky support for the direct link for a full wizard.